# Stripe function has no attribute?

Tags: python, django-views, stripe-payments

Installed stripe on in my django project.
Called Customer function shows error function has no attribute

Imported Stripe on top

```py
import stripe


def charge(request):
    amount = 5
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('Data:', request.POST)

        stripe.Customer.create(
            description="My First Test Customer (created for API docs)",
        )
        
    return redirect(reverse('success', args=[amount]))
```

[Error while checking out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qzLs.jpg)

Comment: In a correct setup, stripe should be a module. Try `print(type(stripe))` and see what's its type. Alternatively you can `print(stripe.__dict__)` to inspect its content

Answer (score 0):

Would you happen to have a file in the same directory under the name stripe.py by any chance?